Dill seedling leaves turning from green to red
This is my first time growing dill (Anethum graveolens) from seed. The seedlings' leaves were initially green, but once the leaves have elongated, the leaves slowly turned red as shown in the photograph below. Is this normal? If not, what could be the issue?


This is completely normal.  Those are the seed leaves, also known as the cotyledons.  They are sort of like a human's first teeth - temporary and fall out when it's time to be replaced.
The cute little branching leaf in the middle is the plant's first 'true leaves'.  Your plant will continue to grow these, it doesn't need the seed leaves any more.

The stem turned red too. Is that normal too?

@Flux I think so.  Mine turn more of a purple color than shown in your image but otherwise look exactly the same.  Enjoy it, one of my favorite herbs :-)

@Flux I finally thought to take a picture of one of my dill seedlings.  The seed leaves are gone already, but you can see the purple stem.  https://i.sstatic.net/VsOXinth.jpg

Thank you for the picture. How many weeks did it take for your plant to go from seed to the state shown in your picture?

@Flux Almost 6 weeks, but they are the seedlings I didn't have room to transplant and left crowded in their small pot.  They are stunted.

@Flux How did your dill do?  I watched my latest batch more carefully, and the stems were purple as I remembered but the cotyledons were actually green.  I don't believe it matters, cotyledons seem to have small contributions to the plant anyway, but now I'm wondering if your red cotyledons were a sign of stress?  Did the plants have any trouble?

Unfortunately, the plants are all dead now. Half of them were eaten by animals (likely birds or slugs). The others were likely killed by heavy rain (rain continuously battering the seedlings and also causing soil compaction). I live near the equator, so the strong sunlight might have caused additional stress.
